# Proof using Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

How would you go along proving this? I've done it for specific function, but can't do it for the general case...

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^bf(x,t) \;dt = \int_a^b\frac{d}{dx}f(x,t) \;dt  $$

Is it even true?

Any help appreciated!

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: What are your assumptions on $f$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: You need some hypothesis on $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, the easiest being continuity in $\Bbb R\times [a,b]$.